# Is it possible to build a custom SQL query in Template Fragment using a Search Term or alternatively the Master doc name which calls the fragment?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to build a custom SQL query in a fragment that uses the Master document's name as a parameter. In saved searches we use the  and pass it via the model document's attributes. But in a custom query for a fragment this is not working.

Alternatively - or even better - it would be great if we could get directly in the query the Master document's name as field.

Is this possible?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(obj_ds.ea_guid, obj_ds.Name) AS [DS_Name-Hyperlink]
FROM t_object obj_adu 
INNER JOIN t_connector tconn 
  ON obj_adu.object_id = tconn.end_object_id 
INNER JOIN t_object obj_ds 
  ON tconn.start_object_id = obj_ds.object_id 
  AND tconn.stereotype = 'Conveyed ADU' 
  AND obj_ds.stereotype = 'Data-Stream' 
INNER JOIN t_objectproperties tobjp_ds
  ON obj_ds.object_id = tobjp_ds.object_id
  AND tobjp_ds.property = 'Source'
INNER JOIN t_object tobj_dm
  ON tobjp_ds.value = tobj_dm.ea_guid
INNER JOIN t_objectproperties tobjp_ds2
  ON obj_ds.object_id = tobjp_ds2.object_id
  AND tobjp_ds2.property = 'Destination'
INNER JOIN t_object tobj_dm2
  ON tobjp_ds2.value = tobj_dm2.ea_guid
INNER JOIN t_objectproperties tobjp_ds3
  ON tobj_dm.ea_guid =  tobjp_ds3.value
  AND (tobjp_ds3.property = 'Element 2' OR tobjp_ds3.property = 'Element 1')
INNER JOIN t_objectproperties tobjp_ds4
  ON tobj_dm2.ea_guid =  tobjp_ds4.value
  AND (tobjp_ds4.property = 'Element 2' OR tobjp_ds4.property = 'Element 1')
INNER JOIN t_object tobj_dm4
  ON tobjp_ds4.Object_id = tobj_dm4.Object_id and tobjp_ds3.Object_id = tobj_dm4.Object_id AND tobj_dm4.stereotype = 'Interface'
INNER JOIN t_attribute tatt
  ON tobj_dm4.Name = tatt.Name
INNER JOIN t_object tobj_dmm
  ON tatt.object_id = tobj_dmm.object_id
  AND tobj_dmm.stereotype = 'model document'
INNER JOIN t_package tpkg_dmm
  on tobj_dmm.package_id = tpkg_dmm.package_id
INNER JOIN t_object tobj_tmmm
  on tpkg_dmm.ea_guid = tobj_tmmm.ea_guid
WHERE obj_adu.object_id = #OBJECTID# AND obj_adu.Stereotype='ADU' AND tobj_tmmm.name LIKE '<Search Term>'
  AND tobj_tmmm.stereotype = 'master document';
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [manual](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_publishing/custom_sql_fragments.html), the only available parameters are the macros:

- #OBJECTID#
- #DIAGRAMID#
- #PACKAGEID#

These macros are related to the **content** you are documenting.
Now if you would use the «master document» Package as the content by dragging it into a «model document» element, you can query the properties of the master document and related elements.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that this query is already using an #OBJECTID# comming from a saved query (called by the model document). How could I simultaneously use the objectid from the query and from the master doc?